# Aerial crop image datasets

Tags: data-request, images, aerial-photography

I am looking for aerial high resolution images of crops taken by drones (corn being the best option) in different states of growth in order to implement a plant counting ML algorithm. I am not finding any.

Does anyone know where to find such datasets ?

Comment: may i have those datasets too? i need to finish my paper.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a few set of aerial images taken by an X8+ Drone with a redEdge camera, maybe they will help you. Contact me.

Comment: Do you offer your data under an open licence?